# max-width not working even apply correct code.

Tags: html, css

I am using this [codepen 404 page](https://codepen.io/) code. The issue is that when I apply CSS to make it responsive with a max width 420px, it is not working.

```css
@media and screen only(max-width: 420px){
.content{margin : 0 15px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="browser-bar">
<span class="close button">Test</span>
<span class="min button">Test</span>
<span class="max button">Test</span>
</div>
<div class="text">inside div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to apply CSS till max width 420px, change your code to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px)
```

example below:

```css
.content {
  margin:0 25%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
.content {
  margin : 0 15px;
  background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="browser-bar">
<span class="close button">a</span>
<span class="min button">v</span>
<span class="max button">n</span>
</div>
<div class="text">w</div>
</div>
```

screen shot of codepen window below 420px:
[image]

Comment: sorry there was a typo, check it now

Comment: Do you check codepen ? Mentioned link in my question? Might not that's why still it is not working

Comment: am sorry, did not really understand the question, what is not working on the codepen ?, i don't see any @media screen and (max-width: 420px) rule in that

Comment: There is not mentioned media rule. I want make media rule. At mobile I want make it responsive but at mobile version it not show properly that's why I am trying to add media rule and it didn't works

Comment: i used the same code in codePen, it seems to be working, check this link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rraVWV

Comment: Yes but there is only change the background right. What about the white bar of image and 3 button which is show left side tip side. It is not show. How we make that page I'm Css responsive. Which look same in mobile but difference would be it size change and marking comes.?

Answer (score -1):

You should have the CSS classes for a desktop if you want desktop first design, and have a media query for small screens with the changes you want.

In this code example, you have all the white bar and the three buttons because the classes are added:

```js
// Typed.js | Copyright (c) 2014 Matt Boldt | www.mattboldt.com
// https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js
!function(t){"use strict";var s=function(s,e){this.el=t(s),this.options=t.extend({},t.fn.typed.defaults,e),this.isInput=this.el.is("input"),this.attr=this.options.attr,this.showCursor=this.isInput?!1:this.options.showCursor,this.elContent=this.attr?this.el.attr(this.attr):this.el.text(),this.contentType=this.options.contentType,this.typeSpeed=this.options.typeSpeed,this.startDelay=this.options.startDelay,this.backSpeed=this.options.backSpeed,this.backDelay=this.options.backDelay,this.stringsElement=this.options.stringsElement,this.strings=this.options.strings,this.strPos=0,this.arrayPos=0,this.stopNum=0,this.loop=this.options.loop,this.loopCount=this.options.loopCount,this.curLoop=0,this.stop=!1,this.cursorChar=this.options.cursorChar,this.shuffle=this.options.shuffle,this.sequence=[],this.build()};s.prototype={constructor:s,init:function(){var t=this;t.timeout=setTimeout(function(){for(var s=0;s<t.strings.length;++s)t.sequence[s]=s;t.shuffle&&(t.sequence=t.shuffleArray(t.sequence)),t.typewrite(t.strings[t.sequence[t.arrayPos]],t.strPos)},t.startDelay)},build:function(){var s=this;if(this.showCursor===!0&&(this.cursor=t('<span class="typed-cursor">'+this.cursorChar+"</span>"),this.el.after(this.cursor)),this.stringsElement){s.strings=[],this.stringsElement.hide();var e=this.stringsElement.find("p");t.each(e,function(e,i){s.strings.push(t(i).html())})}this.init()},typewrite:function(t,s){if(this.stop!==!0){var e=Math.round(70*Math.random())+this.typeSpeed,i=this;i.timeout=setTimeout(function(){var e=0,r=t.substr(s);if("^"===r.charAt(0)){var o=1;/^\^\d+/.test(r)&&(r=/\d+/.exec(r)[0],o+=r.length,e=parseInt(r)),t=t.substring(0,s)+t.substring(s+o)}if("html"===i.contentType){var n=t.substr(s).charAt(0);if("<"===n||"&"===n){var a="",h="";for(h="<"===n?">":";";t.substr(s).charAt(0)!==h;)a+=t.substr(s).charAt(0),s++;s++,a+=h}}i.timeout=setTimeout(function(){if(s===t.length){if(i.options.onStringTyped(i.arrayPos),i.arrayPos===i.strings.length-1&&(i.options.callback(),i.curLoop++,i.loop===!1||i.curLoop===i.loopCount))return;i.timeout=setTimeout(function(){i.backspace(t,s)},i.backDelay)}else{0===s&&i.options.preStringTyped(i.arrayPos);var e=t.substr(0,s+1);i.attr?i.el.attr(i.attr,e):i.isInput?i.el.val(e):"html"===i.contentType?i.el.html(e):i.el.text(e),s++,i.typewrite(t,s)}},e)},e)}},backspace:function(t,s){if(this.stop!==!0){var e=Math.round(70*Math.random())+this.backSpeed,i=this;i.timeout=setTimeout(function(){if("html"===i.contentType&&">"===t.substr(s).charAt(0)){for(var e="";"<"!==t.substr(s).charAt(0);)e-=t.substr(s).charAt(0),s--;s--,e+="<"}var r=t.substr(0,s);i.attr?i.el.attr(i.attr,r):i.isInput?i.el.val(r):"html"===i.contentType?i.el.html(r):i.el.text(r),s>i.stopNum?(s--,i.backspace(t,s)):s<=i.stopNum&&(i.arrayPos++,i.arrayPos===i.strings.length?(i.arrayPos=0,i.shuffle&&(i.sequence=i.shuffleArray(i.sequence)),i.init()):i.typewrite(i.strings[i.sequence[i.arrayPos]],s))},e)}},shuffleArray:function(t){var s,e,i=t.length;if(i)for(;--i;)e=Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1)),s=t[e],t[e]=t[i],t[i]=s;return t},reset:function(){var t=this;clearInterval(t.timeout);var s=this.el.attr("id");this.el.after('<span id="'+s+'"/>'),this.el.remove(),"undefined"!=typeof this.cursor&&this.cursor.remove(),t.options.resetCallback()}},t.fn.typed=function(e){return this.each(function(){var i=t(this),r=i.data("typed"),o="object"==typeof e&&e;r||i.data("typed",r=new s(this,o)),"string"==typeof e&&r[e]()})},t.fn.typed.defaults={strings:["These are the default values...","You know what you should do?","Use your own!","Have a great day!"],stringsElement:null,typeSpeed:0,startDelay:0,backSpeed:0,shuffle:!1,backDelay:500,loop:!1,loopCount:!1,showCursor:!0,cursorChar:"|",attr:null,contentType:"html",callback:function(){},preStringTyped:function(){},onStringTyped:function(){},resetCallback:function(){}}}(window.jQuery);

$(function(){
  $('.text').typed({
    strings: [
      "Oops! It looks like you're lost. <br /> ^1000" + 
      "Sorry about that. <br /> ^1000" +
      "Let me try and help. <br /> ^1000" +
      "Go back <a href='/'>home</a> and start over."
    ],
    typeSpeed: 0,
    showCursor: false
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  line-height: 1.5;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432821596592-e2c18b78144f?dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=960&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=50&w=1440);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
}

  .content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 45px 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  }

  .browser-bar {
    background: #f9f9f3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  }

  .button {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .close {
    background: #fc635d;
  }

  .min {
    background: #fdbc40;
  }

  .max {
    background: #34c84a;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 420px){
.content {
  margin : 0 15px;
  background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="browser-bar">
    <span class="close button"></span>
    <span class="min button"></span>
    <span class="max button"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

[red content with white bar](https://codepen.io/nuriaruiz/pen/zLWPym)

Comment: Please do not circumvent the rules and ignore the big red banner you see when you try to post a link to codepen without any actual code.